# Questions Nagios Monitoring

Tags: performance, monitoring, nagios, process-monitoring

I am a beginner for Nagios and have read the documentation [here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/4/en/toc.html).

However, I still have some questions and appreciate if you can please help me:

1) What are the different metrics that nagios captures? I know, it captures CPU, network, disk metrics etc. But I am looking for more detailed information like CPU idle time, CPU busy time etc?

2) If say for CPU, Nagios captures 5 metrics, where can I get the meaning of each metric captured by Nagios?

3) Can I export the metrics captured by Nagios in a CSV file or to an external database?

4) Can we collect custom metrics?

5) How these metrics are captured by Nagios i.e the mechanism or working of Nagios?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I feel that your questions are somewhat generic. Nagios captures snaphots of data over by frequent sampling. You can always access nagios logs and build your own set of detailed information if you are looking to mine for historical data like busy time and idle time. Logstash Elasticsearch Kibana stack springs to mind.

As far as your third question is concerned, Yes it is possible to get csv outputs for availability. In the nagios/cgi-bin/avail.cgi GET request pass &csvoutput as a parameter  and you will get the csv format availability reports for  all hosts.

Please check this link for more info :

[Link](http://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=29146)

and also:

[Link 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/557210/how-to-script-nagios-csv-export)

Comment: you can export the metrics collected by nagios to mysql DB by using NDOUTILS chek the bellow link                                                                                      https://support.nagios.com/kb/article.php?id=406